# perl help creating an output file based on one or more open files

Tags: perl, file

So far in perl, I know how to open a file for writing like so:

```
open my $par_fh, '>', $par_file
  or die "$par_file: opening for write: $!";
print $par_fh <<PAR;
USERID=$creds
DIRECTORY=DMPDIR
USERS=$users
PAR
close $par_fh
  or die "$par_file: closing after write: $!";
```

What I need help now is with my variable `$user` where in this config file I need to create a comma separate list `USERS=joe,mary,sue,john` with no comma on last item from a separate text file:

users.lst: (this list can get long)

```
joe
mary
sue
john
```

Do I need to open up another a while loop to read in the file? If so, how do I embed that in the file handle that I have already open? Can someone show me a good technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a file for reading is much the same as for writing:

```
open my $par_fh, '<', 'users.lst' or die 'unable to read users.lst';
```

You can then read in one line at a time:

```
my @users;
while (my $line = <$par_fh>) {
  chomp($line); # Remove newline
  push @users, $line;
}
```

Or all at once:

```
my @users = <$par_fh>
chomp(@users); # Remove newlines from all elements
```

Close the file:

```
close($par_fh);
```

Create your config line:

```
my $output = 'USERS=' . join(',', @users);
```

And open and write to the file as you already have.

Comment: `open my $par_fh, '<', 'users.lst' || die 'unable to read users.lst';` is horribly and terribly wrong, and causes a very subtle bug where your die statement is never executed. Read the operator precedence list in perldoc perlop: `||` has higher precedence than `,` (comma).

Comment: Since I have `$par_file` open already, is it ok for me to have another `open` in the next line for reading the `users.lst` file, followed by the `while`? Since I'm writing to a file already. I'm just trying to figure out how to merge that code with my current. Thanks

Comment: @NooberGoober Of course you can have several active file handles open at the same time.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 1):

You can read all lines from a file into an array like

```
my @users = <$user_fh>;
```

remove all newlines at once:

```
chomp @users;
```

and then join all of them into a single string, by seperating each item with `,`:

```
my $users = join ',', @users;
```

Then, we can interpolate that as usual;

```
print "USERS=$users\n";
```

Another solution doesn't do an explicit `join`, but sets the `$"` variable. This is the string that is put between array elements when we interpolate an array:

```
my @array = 1..4;
print "[@array]\n"; #=> "[1 2 3 4]";
```

Normally, this is a single space, but we can set it to a comma:

```
local $" = ",";
print "USERS=@users\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this before the PAR file processing.

```
open INPUT, "users.lst" or die $!;
while (<INPUT>) {
    chomp;
    push @users, $_;
}
close INPUT;
$user = "USERS=" . join(",", @users);
```